# Is there a way to know if the architecture of my cpus allows me to change the frequency per cpu?

Tags: linux, x86, operating-system, intel

I want to buy an Intel Pentium N4200 based single board computer.
How do I know if I can change the frequency of each cpu core on linux ?

I did try cpufreq utils command tools on my own laptop but did not work as the cpu cores are all affected.
However, it would be great to get some low level information before buying it for my project.

Comment: Related: discussion on [Running two functions at the exact same time on multiple cores](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/129096463) - in my experience, mainstream client CPUs (like my Skylake desktop) have all cores on the same multiplier, at least for non-turbo.  
Jérôme Richard reports that turbo frequencies can differ between cores.  But that's Sandybridge-family, not Silvermont-family like I think a Pentium N4200 is; could be very different.

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes. How about https://www.directindustry.com/prod/dfi/product-163687-2432385.html?

Comment: That has early Sandybridge-family CPUs, so if I'm right about how my CPU works, the frequencies of all its cores would be tied together.  (Except maybe turbo giving per-core differences).  That's also quite an old chipset; the newest CPU you can put in it is Ivy Bridge from 2012 or so, a decade old and already discontinued.  If you can get one 2nd-hand for cheap, sure I guess, if you don't need it to run very fast or be as power efficient.